# android/bitmap.h: No such file or directory (after updating Android SDK tools to revision 14)

Tags: android, ant, sdk, android-ndk

After installing Android SDK tools revision 14 and fixed build.xml I cant build native lib.
Error message:

```
Compile++ thumb: ******* <= native/******/src/********.cpp
native/*********/src/******.cpp:7:28: error: android/bitmap.h: No such file or directory
```

Project build  works wonderfully, but native build not.

LOCAL_LDLIBS + =-ljnigraphics included in the Android.mk  file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you have

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

in your Application.mk file?